# Does parent class also need to implement Cloneable interface if we want to clone subclass?

Tags: java

If i want to clone an object in java. So i have to implement Cloneable interface. But in case if that class is a subclass of another class than did i have to also mark(i.e. implement) the parent class as Cloneable.

Is this works?

```
public class A{

    private String a;

    public A(String a){
         this.a = a;
    }
}

public class B extends A implements Cloneable{

    private String b;

    public B(String a, String b){
        super(a);
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        B b1 = new B("a","b");
        B b2 = b1.clone(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Every class is a subclass of `Object`, which doesn't implement `Cloneable`.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @Mayank NO,not needed you are cloning class B which is independent class and its just inheriting the properties of class A.Try it and check it will work

Comment: @TedHopp: I tried it  and it worked. But i am confused because in case of serializing an object you also have to implement serializable to inheritance tree. and if you not implement in case of seralizable the constructor runs for the parent class. So i thought if i am not implementing seralizable in parent than it will run give default value.

Comment: @MayankGupta - Yes, they are different mechanisms, necessarily. Cloning works by simply copying field values (making a shallow copy) while serializing means converting all data reachable through the object (except volatile fields) into a sequence of bytes. The docs for [`Object#clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) and for [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) explain the different requirements.

Comment: @TedHopp: What i came to understand is like, once you extend a class you inherit it's properties so now these inherited properties belong to the child class. So if cloneable implemented by child class only than it is fine because all properties are already inherited by child and no need to make parent Cloneable.

Comment: @MayankGupta - It's not that simple. For instance, private members are not inherited (see the [Java Language Specification, 8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2), yet declaring a subclass to implement `Cloneable` will (using the default `clone()` implementation) correctly copy the superclass's `private` field values into the new subclass instance. (So accessor methods, for instance, will return correct values.)

Answer (score 0):

**NO**,not needed you are cloning `class B` which is independent class and

> class B just inheriting the properties of class A.

So it has nothing to do with the object `class B` object `clone`.

Try it and check it will work

Comment: Class B is not inheriting the private variable of super class, so how it is working. And it should be the same as serializable where we need to implement the marker interface(Serializable) to the super class(if don't want to lose the state of super class also

Answer (score 0):

**It is not required by Parent class to implement Cloneable to make Subclass eligible for cloning.**

*Any subclass can simply implements Cloneable and override clone method to be eligible for cloning.*

```
package com.pradeep.java.practise.object;

class A{
    private String name;
    public A() {
        System.out.println("===A()===");
    }
    public A(String name){
        System.out.println("===A(-)===");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [name=" + name + "]";
    }

}

class B extends A  implements Cloneable{
    private String name;
    public B() {
        System.out.println("===B()===");
    }
    public B(String name){
        System.out.println("===B(-)===");
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        return super.clone();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
public class SubclassCloneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        B b = new B("sub class");
        B clonedB = (B) b.clone();
        System.out.println("original B = "+b);
        System.out.println("cloned B = "+clonedB);

    }

}
```

**Output :**

```
===A()===
===B(-)===
original B = B [name=sub class]
cloned B = B [name=sub class]
```